# Save MSAL cache, even when reloading the browser?

Tags: msal.js

I'm relatively new to MSAL and have come upon a problem that is really frustrating me.
The program I'm making is a single-page app in the browser, and the problem that I'm having is that when you close the page and go back into it, all the login info is wiped.

That's most likely to it being stored in SessionStorage, so i tried doing this in the configuration to change it to LocalStorage (that of should stay):

```
cache: {
    CacheLocation: 'localStorage'
  },
```

It didn't change a thing. I tried editing some of the MSAL code to make it store in localStorage, and it did actually save it in localStorage, only for it to have the same problem. I've also tried making it save to the cookies using this:

```
cache: {
    storeAuthStateInCookie:true
  },
```

But it kept the good stuff in LocalStorage (that of didn't work) and put the information i needed into the cookies like so:
[image: Useless stuff]

Although, when going out of it and back in, the cookies were wiped. Gone! What the hell is going on here, i just want my users to sign in and stay signed in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cache config, you should be setting 'cacheLocation' instead of 'CacheLocation'. MSAL configuration attributes are case sensitive, so you should have something like:

```
cache: {
   cacheLocation: "localStorage"
}
```

However, if credentials are being cleared even from `localStorage`, you should try different browsers to make sure this isn't related to your browser being configured to clear it's storage when closing the window.